# Displaying values of box sizes Why are the values of the box-dimensions displayed in a box the values from the previous box?

Tags: tex-core, boxes

Why are the values of the box-dimensions displayed in a box the values from the previous box?

```
\parindent=0pt
\newdimen\columnwidth%
\columnwidth=100pt%

\def\text{This is the text to fill all the boxes. This is the text to fill all the boxes. This is the text to fill all the boxes. .\vskip\baselineskip}
\def\values{\vbox{ \vskip\baselineskip \bf height \the\ht0 \vskip0.2\baselineskip%
 depth \the\dp0 \vskip0.2\baselineskip%
 width \the\wd0 \vskip0.2\baselineskip}}%to show the values in the text
 
 %endofdefinitions
 {\bf Question about vboxes and their dimensions}\vskip\baselineskip 
 Why are the values of the previous column shown, not of the current column?\vskip\baselineskip 
\hbox{%
\setbox0=\vtop{\hsize\columnwidth %
} %an empty box
\copy0
\hskip0pt\setbox0=\vtop {\hsize\columnwidth\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip %
\text
\values
\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
} %
\copy0%
\hskip10pt\setbox0=\vtop { \hsize\columnwidth\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip %
\text\text
\values
\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
} %
\copy0%
\hskip10pt\setbox0=\vtop { \hsize\columnwidth\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip %
\text\text\text
\values
\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
} %
\copy0%
\hskip10pt\setbox0=\vtop { \hsize\columnwidth\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip %
\text\text\text\text
\values
\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
} %
\copy0%
}%

\bye%
```

Answer (score 1):

you are outputting the values when box has the previous column.

```
\hskip10pt\setbox0=\vtop { \hsize\columnwidth\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip %
\text\text\text
\values
```

here you have just typeset `\text\text\text` but the assignment to box 0 has not yet been made as the `vbox` is not finished so box 0 has the box from the previous assignment

Comment: Thought so. Do you have a solution to display it right? If I call the values outside of the box, the whole column (box) setting is destroyed.

Comment: @user284656 use a vbox (with no assignment) for your columns and within that save the text in  a box and output its dimensions then close the column

Answer (score 0):

Simpler example:

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\makevoid#1{\setbox#1=\box\voidb@x}
\catcode`@=12

\makevoid0
\setbox0=\hbox{This box has width \the\wd0} % expected 0pt

\box0

\makevoid0
\setbox0=\hbox{\hskip10pt}
\setbox0=\hbox{This box has width \the\wd0} % expected 10pt

\box0

\bye
```

I added `\makevoid0` in order to be sure that the box register is void. What do you expect that `\the\wd0` expands to?

I'm expecting `0pt` and `10pt`, because TeX has no way to know the width of the box it's currently building *until* the build-up has been completed. TeX continues to absorb tokens and to append items to a horizontal list (because we've told it to build an `\hbox`); the list will be finalized upon executing `}`. Only after this finalization, the built horizontal list is assigned to box register 0.

[image]

Let's see your example. I made a few changes, mainly for readability. However, the removal of most `%` characters has been done purposefully. Many of them were unnecessary, a few were potentially *harmful*: I'm referring to `\copy0%` which is decidedly wrong. I also removed the useless `\hbox` wrapper.

```
\parindent=0pt
\newdimen\columnwidth
\columnwidth=100pt

\def\text{This is the text to fill all the boxes.
  This is the text to fill all the boxes. This is the text
  to fill all the boxes.\vskip\baselineskip}
\def\values{{\bf
  height \the\ht0 \vskip0.2\baselineskip
  depth \the\dp0 \vskip0.2\baselineskip
  width \the\wd0 \vskip0.2\baselineskip
}}%to show the values in the text
 
{\bf Question about vboxes and their dimensions}\vskip\baselineskip 
Why are the values of the previous column shown, not of the current column?
\vskip\baselineskip 

% -1-
\setbox0=\vtop{\hsize\columnwidth
} %an empty box
\copy0
% -2-
\hskip0pt\setbox0=\vtop {\hsize\columnwidth\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
  \text
  \values
  \hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
}
\copy0
% -3-
\hskip10pt\setbox0=\vtop {\hsize\columnwidth\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
  \text\text
  \values
  \hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
}
\copy0
% -4-
\hskip10pt\setbox0=\vtop {\hsize\columnwidth\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
  \text\text\text
  \values
  \hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
}
\copy0
% -5-
\hskip10pt\setbox0=\vtop {\hsize\columnwidth\hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
  \text\text\text\text
  \values
  \hrule width\hsize\vskip\baselineskip
}
\copy0

\bye
```

In -1- you seem to want to ensure box register 0 is void. Use the method with `\voidb@x` shown before. Alternatively, `\hbox{\box0}`, but this might have adverse effects in complicated situations (box registers are *funny* as regards to groups). Note that a void box register does not contain an empty box.

Now you should know why in -2- you get zero lengths. When TeX expands `\values`, the `\vtop` currently being built hasn't yet finished. Note that TeX first builds a `\vbox` and only at the very end it moves the reference point. It is *impossible* to query this way the sizes of the box being built.